# Input variables with spaces?

Tags: bash

Say I have a script that has:

```
command $1
```

Also say `command` has an optional parameter so it could also be `command $1 $2`.

What happens if `$1` includes a space here *(let us assume `$1=A B`)*? Will command be interpreted as `command A B`, or `command A\ B` where `A B` is a single variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how the user entered it - and then how you reference it in the script

```
./command "a b"
```

or

```
./command a\ b
```

Should provide `$1="a b"` - if you call it elsewhere, you should wrap your argument variable in appropriate quotes - ie, `"$1"`

If the user simply enters

./command a b

Then $1 will contain "a" and $2 will contain "b" and $# (number of args) will be 2.

Try this script as your `command` command -

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Number of arguments given - $#

echo First argument - $1
echo second argument - $2
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if `$1` includes spaces and isn't double-quoted then it will be interpreted as multiple input tokens. If you want it to be interpreted as a single token then double-quote it, i.e. `command "$1" $2`. This is because by default white-space is used to separate tokens. This behavior can be modified by setting the value of the `IFS` environment variable. For more information you might consult the following page from the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide:

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Section 5.1 - Quoting Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)